# Arduino ESP32 Error when uploading any type of file

Tags: arduino, esp32

I just installed the ESP32 library, and every time I try to upload a file to the ESP it gives me this error:

```
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port COM3
Connecting.....
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ6 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
MAC: aa:aa:aa:aA:aa:aa
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Warning: Could not auto-detect Flash size (FlashID=0xffffff, SizeID=0xff), defaulting to 4MB
Compressed 8192 bytes to 47...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet content
A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet content
```

Comment: found any solution? Got in same situation :((

Answer (score 0):

If you use the bare board check for

- Serial monitor closed
- 3.3V stable voltage and
- correct connection via FTDI/USB
- if using a CP210x (driver 2019) or similar you can try lowering the baud rate for flashing to 115200 or/and
- to pull EN to GND (If the board has a boot button then press this one) until the `connect_____.....___` appears then release OR the magic sequence
- Press and hold RESET / Press and release BOOT / Release the RESET

If you have hardware attached:
IO12 must be pulled low on power up as it is also the MTDI line. The device does have a weak pull down on IO12
[See docu page 18 Figure 4](http://espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf)
If you are using it as I2C or similar you may have a pull-up connected. When removing the pull up resistor you could program it.